# How to make elements of an array appear one at the time after clicking submit button?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have following code:

```
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$pollid=(int) $_GET['pollid'];
$questions = array();
$result = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where kysimustik_id="' . $pollid . '"');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $questions[] = $row['kysimus'];
}

$count=count($questions);
$x=0;
while ($x<$count){
    echo $questions[$x];
    $x+=1;
}
?>
<form method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It takes the questions from the database which have kysimustik_id=poll_id and echos them out. But how could I make it work so questions will appear one at the time and new one appears only after I click "Submit" button?

Comment: Do they need to appear below each other on the same page or go to a new page with the next question?

Comment: It needs to replace the old question with new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like the following

```
<div class="row text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Click Here!</button>
    </div>

$(function(){
        var values = [
            "hi",
            "hello",
            "nice",
            "wonderful"
        ];
        var counter = 0;
        $(".btn-lg").on("click", function(){
            if(values.length) {
                counter = (counter + 1) % values.length;
                $('.row.text-center').append(values[counter] + ' ');
            }
        });
});
```

In the above example I have used javascript array. you can easily replace it by your php array

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$pollid=(int) $_GET['pollid'];
 if(isset($_POST['QuestionID'])
{
    $questionID = $_POST["QuestionID"];
    HandleAnswer($pollid,$questionID,$_POST['Answer']);
}
else
{
    $questionID = 0;
}
$questions = array();
$result = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where kysimustik_id="' . $pollid . '"');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $questions[] = $row['kysimus'];
}

function HandleAnswer(string PollId, string QuestionID, string Answer){
  // Implement piece of code that sets the answer in the database,
  // I leave this up to you since i have no Idea how your database is structured


}
 $questionID++;
 $count=count($questions);
 if($questionID < $count){

?>
<form method="post" action="mypage?=<?php echo $pollid; ?>">
<?php echo $questions[$questionID]; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="questionID" value="<?php echo $questionID;?>"/>
<input type="text" name="Answer"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<?php }else{ ?>
THese were all our questions, thank you for answering!
<?php } ?>
```

I didn't test the code myself, but I'm pretty sure it works. Note that this is a hightly unsafe way to do this, because you can edit the value of the hidden field with extensions such as firebug.